# Hide upstream 301 response (react app) on nginx

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx

Here's my setup:

nginx server acting as reverse proxy to route all requests at `mysite.com` - I'm in control of

react app for some subsections of the site on `s3-bucket.awsthing.com` - I'm not in control of

If you visit `s3-bucket.awsthing.com/user/charlie` you get a 301 redirect which sends you to `s3-bucket.awsthing.com/#!/user/charlie` (because that's the index.html where the app is plus some info for routing) in turn returning a 200 ...ok fine.

When a user visits mysite.com/user I have a proxy setup as so

```
location /user/ {
    proxy_pass s3-bucket.awsthing.com/user/;
}
```

which means that the proxy makes a request to `s3-bucket.awsthing.com/user` it returns a 301, then redirects the client to `s3-bucket.awsthing.com/` ... not so good

While it functions and works, I now have the user exposed to the upstream server and not proxied.

questions: 1) How can I make it not show the upstream server 2) Is there a way to not return a 301 to the client and only the redirected 200 stuff?

I've tried just about everything I can think of other than maybe doing some regex to send the proxy request directly to the `/#!` route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass mybucket.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 301 =200 @hide-301;
}

location @hide-301 {
    proxy_pass mybucket.amazonaws.com;
}
```